# I'm trying to install BigVideo.js using Bower for my first time - and all instructions have left me lost

Tags: file, installation, bower

Here's what I've done:

- Got familiar with command line.
- Installed: Node & NPM, Git & installed Bower globally.
- installed and $ bower init the project

And here's I stand in the terminal ...

....."

```
bigvideo.js#1.1.5 bower_components/bigvideo.js
├── imagesloaded#3.1.8
├── jquery#2.1.4
├── jquery-ui#1.11.4
└── video.js#4.12.10
TODD-HANEYs-MacBook:~ toddhaney1$ bower install bigvideo.js --save
bower cached        git://github.com/dfcb/BigVideo.js.git#1.1.5
bower validate      1.1.5 against git://github.com/dfcb/BigVideo.js.git#*
bower no-json       No bower.json file to save to, use bower init to create one
TODD-HANEYs-MacBook:~ toddhaney1$ bower init
? name: "video-big"
? version: 0.0.0
? description: "Background Video Plug in for websites"
? main file:
```

".....

I don't know where my project folder is or what's in it, but, in order to make a json file, I am supposed to answer very specific questions about what's inside of it when I don't even know where it is.

None of the help, articles or tutorials explained "how," they just say "what" to do with technical terms that don't help the beginner.

If anyone could tell me what my next steps are, (where my file is) and basically HOW I get started with bower and any advice on what to use, Grunt etc...

Thanks in advance to anyone who offers an answer...